# "Quench bloodthirst"? Is this correct?

Tags: phrasing

I was writing a text and got to this part.

"Characters can turn hostile quickly, drawing in interested bystanders that will either help the player or try to kill them. Nothing less than murder will quench their bloodthirst."

Is the whole idea clear? But more importantly, is the expression "quench their bloodthirst correct?

Comment: Apart from this being off topic on this SE. The idea is clear and the expression is correct.

Comment: I wouldn't use "quench bloodthirst" other than literally—in reference to a vampire or a mosquito.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quench is a perfectly acceptable verb in this context. *Sate* or *satiate* would also work.

I would also say that, in my experience, *blood**lust*** is a more common usage as a noun than *blood**thirst*** although bloodthirsty is more usual as an adjective. But bloodthirst is not wrong.

As an aside if you are interested in this sort of vocabulary have a look at Seamus Heaney's translation of Beowulf.